# Wrap cursor in html in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, range

I'm looking to wrap a cursor in `span` tags in a contenteditable `div`.

Example (cursor represented by `|`):

- Before:

`The fox jumps |`

- After:

`The fox jumps <span>|</span>`

Any attempt to modify the innerHTML results in the cursor being moved to the end of the line. I'd like it to be inserted *in between* the new HTML `span`'s.

Comment: Do you really mean the cursor or are you talking about a pipe character?

Comment: The pipe is meant to be the cursor, sorry I should have clarified that.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your code in a JS fiddle?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/dRqbr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible cross-browser because of implementation issues. Attempting to place the caret within an empty inline element such as a `<span>` in both WebKit and IE will actually place the caret immediately before the element. The following demonstrates this: it will do you what you expect in Firefox but not WebKit or IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/8TTb3/1/

You can use a [DOM Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range) and the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection) API to insert elements at the caret position, except in IE < 9 which does not support these and instead has its own API.

Code:

```
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement("span");
range.insertNode(span);
range.setStart(span, 0);
range.setEnd(span, 0);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Comment: Cool thanks for your help. When you say *at* the caret position, do you mean *after*, *before* or *both*?

Comment: @Matt: Definitely *at*, assuming that you agree that the caret position can be represented as a numeric offset within a node.

Comment: Hmm, okay yah I see what you mean. I guess I should have been more clear in my description, but I'm basically looking to do exactly what say, jsfiddle is doing with their highlighting - adding `span`'s without messing with cursor position. Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do a trick:

```
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "&#8203;";
range.insertNode(span);
range.setStart(span, 0);
range.setEnd(span, 1);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

works in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/8TTb3/8/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can control is the position of the cursor in the (already parsed) contents of the div. If you put a span in there it will be parsed before the cursor is inserted by the browser, at which point the cursor will be either before it or after it.

So no, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Well I'm thinking, you can move the cursor after you do the insert and the content is parsed. Or perhaps not use innerHTML at all and use a more precise method.